# Can modern browsers prevent against a DNS Spoof attack?

Tags: dns, spoofing

Are modern browsers capable of blocking all DNS spoofing attacks as they use HSTS or is it still possible to spoof?

Comment: Not if the website doesn't use HSTS.  HSTS is initiated by the server not the browser.

Comment: The two are unrelated. If you never reached to a specific website, you can not know its HSTS policy, except if it is on the HSTS preloading list. But trying to mitigate a problem at the DNS level with something that happens far later (in HTTP) is not the right way to do things. Defending against DNS spoofing already has a proper solution: DNSSEC